# Css overflow not working

Tags: css

I have a div with css setting overflow auto but noscrollbar appears whereas once i have visited some other page it comes on the page.

Also if possible how can I remove overflow style of div?

Comment: Please post some code so we can help - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The overflow auto only shows scrollbars when the content exceeds the size of the element...

Do you have some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) for an overview of the overflow property.

Answer (score 0):

> Also if possible how can I remove
>   overflow style of div?

The default value is [visible](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want this?

```
overflow: scroll;
```